# PostgreSQL ALTER SEQUENCE with SELECT clause

Tags: postgresql, database-sequence

I am trying to alter database sequence and restart it with value returned by complex `SELECT` statement. This is a simplified example that I prepared to replicate the issue:

```sql
ALTER SEQUENCE
    abc.my_seq
RESTART WITH
    (SELECT 1234)
```

When I run this query, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
```

Why am I receiving this error? Is it possible to set the value of a sequence based on returned value of `SELECT` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setval()`  instead

```
select setval('abc.my_seq', (select ... 
                             from ...));
```

Note the parentheses around the select.

Comment: Thank you, this works. Is there a reason why my initial try (`ALTER SEQUENCE abc.my_seq RESTART WITH (SELECT 1234)`) doesn't work? Is it simply not allowed by-design in PostgreSQL?

Comment: DDL statements typically do not allow parameters to be specified by queries